# Having IMethodSymbol is it possible in Roslyn to figure out all the methods and fields used/called from within that method?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have the `IMethodSymbol` object and I want to figure out all the methods and fields used/called from that method.

I do it already with Mono.Cecil. However, this is not good enough, because any code involving dynamic types is just reflection. So, inspecting the binary code is useless here - we must examine the source code.

Hence, I have the `IMethodSymbol` of the method which I know uses dynamic parameters (It calls `Binder.InvokeMember`). I know source code analysis can tell me what method is being called.

I am familiar with the `SymbolFinder` class and was able to use its `FindReferencesAsync` method. But I do not see how I can use it for my purpose, i.e. given the method find all the symbols used by it.

What am I missing?

**EDIT 1**

So I figured out how to get the top level operation:

```
var op = model.GetOperation(method.DeclaringSyntaxReferences[0].GetSyntax());
```

Where `model` is the respective `SemanticModel` instance and `method` is my `IMethodSymbol`. But there are literally gazillion kinds of `IOperation`'s. I need a convenient way to navigate them. I guess `OperationWalker` is what I need. Will continue to explore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way - `OperationWalker`.

In my case I have the following "walker" (work in progress):

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Operations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CSTool
{
    public class DynamicOperationWalker : OperationWalker
    {
        public readonly List<IMethodSymbol> Result = new();
        public readonly List<(SyntaxNode,string)> Unresolved = new();

        public override void VisitDynamicIndexerAccess(IDynamicIndexerAccessOperation operation)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void VisitDynamicInvocation(IDynamicInvocationOperation operation)
        {
            var memberReferenceOp = (IDynamicMemberReferenceOperation)operation.Operation;
            switch (memberReferenceOp.Instance.Type)
            {
                case INamedTypeSymbol type:
                    {
                        var memberName = memberReferenceOp.MemberName;
                        var members = type.GetMembers(memberName);
                        if (members.Length > 1)
                        {
                            throw new NotImplementedException();
                        }
                        Result.Add((IMethodSymbol)members[0]);
                        break;
                    }

                case IDynamicTypeSymbol dynamicType:
                    Unresolved.Add((operation.Syntax, memberReferenceOp.MemberName));
                    break;
            }
        }

        public override void VisitDynamicMemberReference(IDynamicMemberReferenceOperation operation)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void VisitDynamicObjectCreation(IDynamicObjectCreationOperation operation)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And I invoke it like this in order to inspect the body of the method given by `methodSymbol`:

```
var op = model.GetOperation(methodSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences[0].GetSyntax());
var walker = new DynamicOperationWalker();
walker.Visit(op);
```

I am only interested in the dynamic invocations, since non dynamic are given to me by `Mono.Cecil`.